# Could not find main class (Maven Mojo Plugin Error)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

It seems that Maven (with JPA hibernate running on NetBeans) can't locate the main class, although it refers to its path. The error I get looks like this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class app.Main
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.229s
Finished at: Wed Sep 18 15:25:26 EEST 2019
Final Memory: 5M/123M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project 
jpa_test: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="_one2manyJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>model.Student</class>
        <class>model.Course</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa_base?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="rootpass"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>


    </properties>



</project>
```

and the main:

```
    package app;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import model.Course;

/**
 *
 * @author mousa
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("_one2manyJPA");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Course c = em.find(Course.class, 1); //retrieve

        Course c1 = new Course();
        c1.setTitle("Algebra");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(c1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();




        System.out.println(c.getTitle());
    }

}
```

I can't find any mistake inside the xmls which could cause this. Could it be an internal problem with my Maven install?

UPDATE: nbactions.xml includes the mojo plugin inside the goals tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
        <action>
            <actionName>run</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath app.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>debug</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath app.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
                <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>profile</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath app.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
            </properties>
        </action>
    </actions>
```

Is there a problem with this file?

Comment: You have shown us the `main` method, but not the whole class `app.Main`!

Comment: Additionally, I am confused. There is no configuration for the `exec-maven-plugin` in your POM. Yet it fails on running this plugin ?!?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose updated the main snippet. The mojo plugin thing is a mystery for me too.

Comment: Then it is not running the current situation!

Comment: Include your plugin XML

Comment: @djb can you elaborate on that?

Comment: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec was released September 2011.  I wouldn't use anything that old.  Usually your pom file has a plugins section, with execution/goals section, configuration section, etc.  Not sure how you'd run the mojo plugin without that section.

Comment: @djb my pom.xml is exactly as shown above, no plugins included, that's why it seems strange to me. There is another xml though, which seems to have this plugin included. I'm posting it now.

Answer (score 0):

try add this in your pom, and run 
`mvn clean install`  (change 1.8 to 1.7 if you're running java 7)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: No luck. This 'mojo' plugin has messed everything up.

Comment: I would ditch the mojo plugins.  They're basically obsolete, so much has changed in the last 8 years.    Delete that nbactions.xml file, which is some netbeans nonsense, add the plugin here, and try mvn clean install from the command line, in the pom.xml directory, for now.  What does it say?